# Mobile app which connect with miband

Tags: android, mobile

I am working on a university project, and I have to make a mobile app that connects with a smart band (Specifically "Xiaomi Mi Band 3"). I don't have so much experience in this type of projects and it is being quite difficult.

I have found some projects that help making the connection with the smartband and read the information about Windows projects, but I haven't found much information on how I can do the app on Android.

**Q:** What library or framework do you think is the easiest for this task?

As I said, I don't have so much experience with this type of programming, and I would like software with documentation, examples and information.

Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a university project and I have to make the app.
No bad feelings. I appreciate you correcting the mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for clarification and updating! I've cleaned up comments then. If you need some inspirations: the app I was referring to is [Gadgetbridge](https://codeberg.org/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge). It's open source, so it might be helpful for your project. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are trying to make something like [Mi fit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xiaomi.hm.health&hl=en_GB), or   [Notify & Fitness for Mi Band](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xiaomi.hm.health&hl=en_GB)?
Most Android development is in Java. You **can** use other languages, but will get more support for Java.

Since the Xiaomi Mi Band 3 communicates by BlueTooth, you will have to study that. The Mi 3 version uses BT 4, not the new BT 5; I do not know what the new v4, due out in September (IIRC) uses.

If you don’t want to learn Java, or think your app might ever be cross platform, you can look into [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) which lets you produce cross-platform, native apps by coding in JavaScript. It is popular and well supported.

If you already know C++ or Pascal, look at [Embarcadero](https://www.embarcadero.com/)’s RAD IDE, which will let you write your code once and generate apps for Windows, Linux, Mac, Android & iOs. Sounds great? It is; I love it. ***BUT*** it costs over $1,000 :-(  However, you don’t need to pay that until you make more than $5k, so maybe the high price is “a happy problem”.

You can ask general Android questions at our [Android enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) sister site. When you have coding problems, ask at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and 1) post code, 2) say what it should do 3) say what it is doing instead.

Comment: Yes, I am trying something similar to Mi Fit. I have tried unsuccessfully with javascript. I thought there was more information in Javascript. I have no problem with Java so I am going to try with it now. 

I'll also take a look at 'Embarcadero’s RAD IDE'

Thanks for your answer

Comment: "` I have tried unsuccessfully with javascript`" - well, I doubt that you were trying to conenct via BlueTooth; that's the important part. I love Embarcadero's IDE, but there is probably more support for Java on Android. BUT, if you might, just might, ever want to make it cross platform, then plan for it now (and don't forget React Native, which handles BlueTooth). It migh tbe best to go wiht a language that you already know. Good luck